# How to convert a dataset of type String to Dataset of type Row?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a dataset of type `String` to Dataset of type `Row` using Apache java spark:

```
Dataset<String> dataDs = spark.createDataset(dataList,Encoders.STRING());
```

`dataDs` need to be converted to type `Row`.

Answer (score 3):

A `DataSet[Row]` is called a `DataFrame` in Spark. Instead of using the `spark.createDataset` method, you can use `spark.createDataFrame`.

It is also possible to convert a dataset to a dataframe using the `toDF` function.

```
DataFrame df = dataDs.toDF()
```